Can You Create a Time-Locked PSBT in Bitcoin?
I am exploring the capabilities of Partially Signed Bitcoin Transactions (PSBTs) and am particularly interested in incorporating time locks. Is it possible to create a PSBT that includes a time lock condition in Bitcoin? If so, how can one implement this feature, and what are the limitations or considerations to keep in mind?

PSBT can contain any unsigned transaction. If that transaction uses a script with a locktime condition, then you have a PSBT that involves a time lock.
Whether or not wallet software can deal with such transactions is up to them. PSBT is just a means of communicating the transaction and partial signatures.
